# Highcharts in R: sort xAxis in Line Chart

Tags: r, sorting, highcharts, linechart

I have a simple line chart, but some categories do not have all periods (xAxis), so the xAxis is not ordered at the end.

**That is an example data:**
The chart looks like that (with "2019-01" and "2019-03" exchanged) [image]

**Example Code**

```
df <- data.frame(PERIODO = c("2017-01","2017-03","2018-01","2018-03",
                             "2018-03","2019-01",rep("2019-03",2),
                             "2020-01"),
                 CATEGORIA = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2),"A","B","B"),
                 FRECUENCIA = c(2,3,3,1,2,4,1,1,2))

    highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
      hc_add_series(df, "line",
                    hcaes(x = PERIODO, y = FRECUENCIA, 
                          group = CATEGORIA),
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                      style = list(fontSize = '13px'))
      ) %>% 
      hc_legend(enabled = TRUE, align = "right",layout = 'vertical',verticalAlign= "middle") %>% 
      hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE
                 ,style = list(fontSize = "18px")
```

Someone knows about how to keep the xAxis order by PERIODO: 2017-01,2017-03,2018-01,2018-03,2019-01,2019-03,2020-01

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put your dates `PERIODO` in `Date` format (use first day of the month if you only have months).

```
df$PERIODO <- as.Date(paste0(df$PERIODO, "-01"))
```

Then, use `type = "datetime"` instead of `category` for your `hc_xAxis` argument. You can indicate what you want as labels on your x-axis using `dateTimeLabelFormats`.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", 
           dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b %Y')) %>%
  ...
```

Default labels and more information can be found [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats).